# How to prevent page reload after submit button clicked for bootstrap modal and parsley.js validation?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, parsley.js

I have bootstrap modal which open up a modal to allow user to enter the form and it works. I implemented parseley.js for the form validaton and it kinda works. The problem is when the validation passed, it reload the page (as you can see from below gif) which it not the behavior I expect.  What I expect is to see the `alert('ok')` in `validateForm()`.

[image]

This is how I define my form tag and submit button

```
<form id="myForm" data-parsley-validate="">
    <button class="btn btn-default" >Save</button>           
</form>
```

and this is my function to validate the form using Parsely.js. When all validation pass,  I expect is to see the `alert('ok')` but it doesn't. Instead, it reload the page.

```
function validateForm() {
    $('#myForm').parsley().on('field:validated', function () {
        debugger
        var ok = $('.parsley-error').length === 0;
        $('.bs-callout-info').toggleClass('hidden', !ok);
        $('.bs-callout-warning').toggleClass('hidden', ok);
    })

        .on('form:submit', function () {
            debugger
            alert('ok') // I expect to reach here when pass validation pass but it doesn't
            postCustomer();
            return false; 
        });
}
```

and this is my bootstrap modal

```
$('#modalCustomerForm').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    debugger
    validateForm();
    return false;
})
```

If I add sample code below, there is no css class added by parsley. I suspect parsley is not loading. But then, the validation work. When I press Submit button, I can see red color error message at the bottom of the textbox.

```
<div class="bs-callout bs-callout-warning hidden">
    <h4>Oh snap!</h4>
    <p>This form seems to be invalid :(</p>
</div>

<div class="bs-callout bs-callout-info hidden">
    <h4>Yay!</h4>
    <p>Everything seems to be ok :)</p>
</div>
```

Further troubleshooting. If I add an id to the button and create button click event, it doesn't auto reload the page. But if I do so, parsley.js validation doesn't work.

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" id="formBtn">Save</button>

$('#formBtn').on("click", function (e) {
    debugger

    postCustomer();
    debugger
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

That's why I put my `postCustomer()` at here (below) in `validateForm()` but it doesn't work either:

```
.on('form:submit', function () {
    
    debugger
    alert('ok')
    postCustomer();
    return false; // Don't submit form for this demo
});
```

Comment: Can you try this: .on('form:submit' , function(e) { e.preventDefault() }). let me know if this works!

Comment: @dhruwlalan. I tried but still the same issue.

Comment: Is your submit event handler even working? If not; try `"submit"` instead of `"form:submit"` as the event parameter.

Comment: just `submit` doesn't work. `form:submit` works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you don't have nested form tags in your rendered code like this one below:

```html
<form data-parsley-validate="">
    <form id="#myForm" data-parsley-validate="">
        <button class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form> 
</form>
```

You can check this part once the page is rendered in the browser. Otherwise, you don't have `stopPropagation` method in your code and it is possible that the parent form is submitted and the page is reloaded.

The following statement in your code shoud stop form submitting, just remove other lines in your method for testing.

```js
.on('form:submit', function (e) {
    console.log("form submitted after validation");
    return false;
}
```

So, in your code, it is possible you have some issues (exceptions) in the methods above `return false`. As a hack, you can easily add a new event without changing your code.

```js
$('#myForm').submit(function (e)
{
    console.log("form submit called");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

If `return false` doesn't help, this new event should. It is called on the top of the form, after your validation.

Comment: @Steve is this helped you?

Comment: If I define an id at the button with click event, the validation doesn't work. If I don't define an id at the button, the validation work but it reload the page automatically.

Comment: @Steve pay attention, this is not event on the button. This is event directly on the form. There is no new ids added or html structure modification.

Comment: I realize that I have to put the ` $('#myForm').parsley()...` on the root. Thanks it works now.

Comment: I have updated form identifier in the code to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the event from the form submission and stop it from going the default way which is reloading the page after the form submission.

```
.on('form:submit', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
debugger
alert('ok')
postCustomer();
return false; // Don't submit form for this demo
```

});